# How to partially test shape and partially test values of a json object

Tags: javascript, json, mocha.js, chai

I would like to test the shape of my json in my mocha expectations. Some things I know like 'name' but others(_id) come from the database. For them, I only care that they are set with the proper type.

Here I have my expectation:

```
expect(object).to.eql({
  recipe:
  {
    _id: '5fa5503a1fa816347f3c93fe',
    name: 'thing',
    usedIngredients: []
  }
})
```

I would rather do something like this if possible:

```
expect(object).to.eql({
  recipe:
  {
    _id: is.a('string'),
    name: 'thing',
    usedIngredients: []
  }
})
```

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this? Or is it best to just break this up into multiple tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using [chai-json-pattern](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-json-pattern/) plugin.

> Chai JSON pattern allows you to create blueprints for JavaScript objects to ensure validation of key information. It enables you to use JSON syntax extends with easy to use validators. It came up mostly for testing API with cucumber-js but can be used in any application. Additionally, you can extend base functionality with custom validators

E.g.

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiJsonPattern = require('chai-json-pattern').default;
chai.use(chaiJsonPattern);
const { expect } = chai;

describe('64715893', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const object = {
      recipe: {
        _id: Math.random().toString(),
        name: 'thing',
        usedIngredients: [Math.random() + 'whatever'],
      },
    };
    expect(object).to.matchPattern(`{
      "recipe": {
        "_id": String,
        "name": "thing",
        "usedIngredients": Array,
      },
    }`);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  64715893
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (50ms)
```